# Implementing IFB_LLLLCHAR

Tags: java, jpos

We are using jpos server with ASCIChannel and custom package which contains one field with max length 9999. To do this we implemented IFB_LLLLCHAR as follows:

```
public class IFB_LLLLCHAR extends ISOStringFieldPackager {
    public IFB_LLLLCHAR() {
        super(NullPadder.INSTANCE, AsciiInterpreter.INSTANCE, BcdPrefixer.LLLL);
    }
    
    public IFB_LLLLCHAR(int len, String description) {
        super(len, description, NullPadder.INSTANCE, AsciiInterpreter.INSTANCE, BcdPrefixer.LLLL);
        checkLength(len, 9999);
    }

    public void setLength(int len)
    {
        checkLength(len, 9999);
        super.setLength(len);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't use the whole 9999 because if the size of whole message goes over 9999 it throws the following exception while sending it:

```
<exception name="len exceeded">
    java.io.IOException: len exceeded
    at org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel.sendMessageLength(ASCIIChannel.java:80)
    at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.send(BaseChannel.java:528)
    at com.advam.gateway.terminalmanagementserver.gateway.LogUploadFuncTest.testLogUpload(LogUploadFuncTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    </exception>
```

Why am I getting this exception, and how to fix it? I don't have much knowledge about inside of jpos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total length of the complete message cannot exceed 9999 using the AsciiChannel (like @gerrytan already pointed out).

The AsciiChannel assumes a protocol where the first four bytes are the ASCII value of the length digits.

You might want to look at HEXChannel or NACChannel as they can accommodate larger lengths. HEXChannel and NACChannel allow length up to 0xFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [source code for AsciiChannel class](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/iso/channel/ASCIIChannel.java), length is capped at maximum 9999

```
/**
 * @param len the packed Message len
 * @exception IOException
 */
protected void sendMessageLength(int len) throws IOException {
    if (len > 9999)
        throw new IOException ("len exceeded");

    try {
        serverOut.write(
            ISOUtil.zeropad(Integer.toString(len), 4).getBytes()
        );
    } catch (ISOException e) { }
}
```

Also the `checkLength()` method you call isn't actually trimming the length, it only threw exception when the content is too long. if you don't want exceptions then don't call this method / capture the exception and trim it

```
 protected void checkLength(int len, int maxLength) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (len > maxLength)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length " + len + " too long for " + getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have seen that, what you suggest?

Comment: Do not exceed the length

Comment: :) that is what i am already doing to avoid this any suggestion on changing the channels, like this problem is with ASCIChannel is there any other channel which allows larger size messages?

Comment: Please see updated answer, you should do your own trimming if you don't want exceptions to be thrown

Answer (score 1):

The channel definition is something that you have agreed with the system you are talking to. If you need to send more than 9999 you need to change the channel as mentioned in earlier response and so does the other entity. Both sides of the communication need to make sure that they have the same understanding of what the length header is to extract the full message.

Options you have

- Both sides fo the communication channel update the size that can be sent or received by using a different channel.
- You compress the large data encoded as base64, assuming the other side of the comm channel is told about this change so that they can handle it.
- Sometimes the specification/protocol indicates how one can split this data into multiple requests, see if thats available.

Comment: Thanks for this, All your suggestion are true and has already been implemented.